association classes or classes in class diagram?
I know that in a class diagram the difference between an association class and a real class is the dependency. That is, an association class depends on the existence of the instances it connects while a class does not. if I have for example three classes
c1, c2 and c3. with the following associations
a1 connects c1, c2 and c3.
a2 connects c2 and c3.
To create an instance of a1, however, I must verify that an instance of a2 exists. Having said this, should the association a1 be represented in the class diagram as a class or as an association class?
even if they are not present, a1 and a2 have an attribute called year


Your question would be clearer if you actually drew the different UML diagrams for the different options.

I did. If you need further clarification I'm here

The association a1 is a ternary association between c1, c2 and c3.
The constraint that a2 is a prerequisite for a1 does not affect the nature of a1 as simple (ternary) association (i.e. it is not an association class).  It just creates a constraint among the instances of c1,c2 and c3 that can be linked according to a1.
You may however want to consider an alternate model,  in which a1' would associate c1 and a2.  You could then derive the ternary association a1 from a1' and a2. Personally, I'd probably go for this approach, which I find more easy to understand.
Another alternative could be to derive a2 from a1.  Although this sounds nice in theory when looking at letters and digits, this might however not correspond to your requirement that suggest a chronology (i.e. an a2 link must first exist between the instances before considering an a1 link).

If I understand correctly, do you recommend breaking down the ternary association into a binary association that associates c1 and c2? so I don't lose the meaning of the ternary association?

@dok indeed, in this cas it would simplify the design.  However we must lake sure we do not lose semantics (difficult to say with Cn and An)

Since a1 depends on instances of a2, it should be represented as an association class in the class diagram. This shows its dependency on the connections between c1, c2, and c3.

the reason you suggest representing a1 as an association class is because it has an external dependency, right? if this dependency didn't exist it was also fine to represent it as a normal class, right?
